# Go-Gin binding data with one-to-many relationship

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I'm new to Golang and Gin framework, I have created two models

```
type Product struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Media []Media
}

type Media struct {
    gorm.Model
    URI string
    ProductID uint
}
```

and I send a POST request to save a new product, the body was:

```
{
    "name": "Product1",
    "media": [
        "https://server.com/image1",
        "https://server.com/image2",
        "https://server.com/image3",
        "https://server.com/video1",
        "https://server.com/video2"
    ]
}
```

And I save a new product using this code

```
product := Product{}
if err := context.ShouldBindJSON(product); err != nil { // <-- here the error
    context.String(http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("err: %s", err.Error()))
    return
}
tx := DB.Create(&product)
if tx.Error != nil {
    context.String(http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("err: %s", tx.Error))
    return
}
```

the return error message is

```
err: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Product.Media of type models.Media
```

I know that `ShouldBindJSON` can't convert `media-string` to `media-object`, but what is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your payload doesn't match the model. In the JSON body, `media` is an array of strings, whereas in the model it's a struct with two fields and the embedded gorm model.

If you can't change anything of your current setup, implement [`UnmarshalJSON`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) on `Media` and set the `URI` field from the raw bytes. In the same method you may also initialize `ProductID` to something (if needed).

```
func (m *Media) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    m.URI = string(b)
    return nil
}
```

Then the binding will work as expected:

```
        product := Product{}
        // pass a pointer to product
        if err := context.ShouldBindJSON(&product); err != nil {
            // handle err ...
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(product) // {Product1 [{"https://server.com/image1" 0} ... }
```